# Issue with /setblock & /tp @p

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am creating and adventure map and I have this shop to where players can teleport to by pressing a button.

So when they press the button it activates two command block:

```
/tp @p 1016 56 -4060 # Teleports closest player to the shop

/setblock 1015 57 -4063 command_block 0 destroy {Command:"/tp @p[r=3] 1019 56 -4068"} 
# This is supposed to create a command block connected to a button in the shop that lets the player go back to their last position.
```

However, the last command never runs and the Command Block is not created. If I remove the radius limitation, though, it creates the command block, but instead of it having "/tp @p[r=3] 1019 56 -4068", it has "/tp Edoreld @p[r=3] 1019 56 -4068", where Edoreld is my username. What I would like for it to do is not to expand my username. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Okay I tried to rebuild this like you described. I did not tried the first `tp` command I hope this one is working.

Everything I describe here is running in a clean Minecraft 1.8 on a offline map with cheats activated.

The `setblock` command should look like this:

```
setblock -30 79 214 command_block 0 replace {Command:"/tp @p[r=3] -28 79 214"}
```

If you use the command like that it should working as you described. But I do not know what you actully made wrong... The commandblock should be created also with the `@p[r=3]` or only a `@p` inside. It is not possible that the `@p` is changed to the playername.

This commandblock is configured with the command from above.

[image: Example]

This will create a other commandblock two blocks to the left. With the command `/tp @p[r=3] -28 79 214` as configured in the first command.

[image: Example]

**Keep in mind that you have to stay three blocks near the commandblock that is spawing (the right one)!**

Otherwise you are not teleported because of the radius limitation you programmed into the commandblock. If three blocks are not enough you have to increase the number or programm a exact block teleport (if it is possible that other players are selected with a bigger radius).

Comment: That still has the issue that I originally described. /setblock will only execute when it detects a player, and when it does it will replace @p with the name of the player in the target command block. I would like for @p to appear as itself in the target block instead of the username.

Comment: @Edoreld Why should this happen???? Are you talking about the original minecraft without mods? It is not possible that @p is changing to the username. And the setblock command has also nothing to do with a player. It only sets the block...